# How to retrun an array to the list view flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function working on query an array inside subcollcetion i'ts working good when click it test button its showing me data fine but i need to return the data to the list view How can i do this

function get data

```
Future < List > getsubcollcation() async {
    List Rav;
    final firestoreInstance = Firestore.instance;

    firestoreInstance.collection("Institute").document(widget.id_document).collection("Ravs").where('Rav name', isEqualTo: 'English').snapshots().listen((snapshot) {
        Rav = snapshot.documents.toList();
    });
    return Rav;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you're not returning a List Widget but a Future Widget. You have to put the Listview into a FutureBuilder widget. Pass the function that returns the Future as it's 'future' parameter. Then write a builder function,
that first checks if the Future has data yet ( if (Future.Connectionstate == Connectionstate.done )),
then you can return a ListView where you put the Future.data as it's 'children' param.